# how to define a value in a href link

Tags: href

```
var button = '<a href="ticket.html?id"+ 'id' data-ajax="false"><button class="btn">Book Now!</button></a>';
```

How do I define a value(id) in my a href link?

Comment: you have an error in your string concatenation `var button = '<a href="ticket.html?id=' + id + '" data-ajax="false">`

Comment: Hey thanks man, solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jérôme Teisseire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3122786/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-teisseire) said in a comment, try to edit this in your string

```
var button = '<a href="test.html?yourid=' + yourid + '" data-ajax="false">
```